# Using Hugo Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use the *Hugo library* developed by Jake Wharton.

I added the statement:

`compile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'`

to my dependencies in my *build.gradle* file at the app level.

Then when I try to annotate with `@DebugLog` on my methods, it appears in red, as if the IDE doesn't recognize it.

I tried typing in an import statement like:

`import com.jakewharton.hugo;`

but the `jakewharton` part of the import statement appears in red, meaning it doesn't see it.

I've googled, and found references like:

`classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'`

I'm not sure what the difference between compile and classpath is.

Also, I see a reference to:

`apply plugin: 'hugo'`

Where should that go?

As you can see I'm totally lost. Any ideas on how to make this work is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Read README 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure you are referencing the app module build.gradle or the project level build.gradle.

But eventually, I put it all in the app module build.grade and it worked for me. This is how the file looked like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app_name"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: You are referencing yourself as someone else - did you forget to change your account before posting an answer? ;)

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get errors: `Error:(8, 16) error: cannot find symbol class DebugLog`

Comment: Hahahhahahah @SuitUp

Answer (score 1):

A correct configuration would look like this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
  }
}

dependencies {
  // Other dependencies
}
```

There is no need to add Hugo to the second `dependencies` section, this is done for you by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem, but realized I had `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` typed twice. Once I deleted the extra reference, placing the Jake Wharton stuff at the top of build.gradle (app), it removed the red lines.